# How to link anaconda to python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have already installed the [anaconda module](https://www.anaconda.com/download") and it already has built-in `pandas package` that I want to make use of. I have python 3.6 installed in my machine. Environment variables for anaconda and python are set as well but I am still unable to `import pandas` on my python console.

Could anyone help me import the `pandas`? I can not make use of `pip tool` as I am working on my company's machine. Due to security issues, I am not allowed to download any package through `pip`. I want to make use of pre-installed anaconda module. Help me link my python to Anaconda.

Comment: Python is a part of anaconda (which is not a module but a complete installation). Do you have _two_ python binaries now? If so, I would recommend removing both anaconda and the old python and then installing anaconda again. Also, please mention what OS do you use.

Comment: @DYZ oh great. I did not know that and yes it seems like i have two python binaries and i have "Windows 7" Os in my machine. I ll go and try the resolution, given by you

Comment: @DYZ thanks it worked and i am able to load the pandas